# How are the average rate of change and the instantaneous rate of change related for ƒ(x) = 2x + 5?

Tags: calculus

How are the average rate of change and the instantaneous rate of change related for ƒ(x) = 2x + 5 ?

Should I figure out what is similar between them to solve this question? I don't understand how they correlate

Comment: Calculate any average rate of change (over any interval) and then calculate the instantaneous rate of change (at any point) you should notice something about them

Comment: I don't understand how to involve the equation given to get the solution. How can I calculate them with no x's

Comment: Just pick any point, the nature of this problem allows you do do that. $x=2$, for example

Answer (score 4):

The average rate of change is defined as:

$r_{avg} = \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$, over some interval $[a,b]$.

The instantaneous rate of change is defined as the slope of $f$ evaluated at a single point, e.g.: $f'(c)$ where $c$ is a predefined point.

In this case, because $f(x)=2x+5$, we have:

$r_{avg}=\frac{(2b+5)-(2a+5)}{b-a}$=$\frac{2b-2a}{b-a}$=$2$

And you will also note notice that the slope of $f(x)$ is...$2$!

**Addendum:**

The reason that the average rate of change equals the instantaneous is because the slope is constant in this function.

In general, instantaneous change is defined as the **derivative** of the function evaluated at a single point.

The average change is the same as always (pick two points, and divide the difference in the function values by the difference in the $x$ values).

But, if the curve looks like $y=x^2$, this won't be the case. The slope at a single point anywhere along the curve is different, and the average rate of change will not *always* be the same as the instantaneous, though it can for certain points. (See "Mean Value Theorem")